# como usar una clase existente en java desde grails?

Tags: java, grails

Tengo una clase en java queintento utilizar desde grails cual es la mejor manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Exporta tu clase Java como jar. Luego, importa el jar en tu aplicación y accede a los componentes declarados allí.

Comment: En caso que tenga un jar y quiera ejecutar los metodos contenidos en ese jar haciendolo desde una clase java. Y lo q devuelva la clase llamarlo desde un controlador por ejemplo?

Comment: Importas la clase que necesitas y la utilizas como cualquier clase en Groovy.

Comment: No me reconoce la existencia de la clase

Comment: La clase es pública y está en un paquete, cierto?

Comment: Muchas gracias pasaba exactamente eso un error con el paquete pero todo esta funcionando  bien muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu clase hecha en Java debe cumplir con lo siguiente:

- Pertenecer a un paquete.
- Ser declarada pública.
- Tener miembros públicos.

Aquí un ejemplo de una clase:

```
package edu.ltmj.prueba;

public class MiClase {
    public String saluda(String nombre) {
        return String.format("Hola %s", nombre);
    }
}
```

Luego, debes empaquetar esta clase en un jar. Para ello, deberás compilar la clase y generar el jar respectivo. Por ejemplo si se tiene el paquete y la clase dentro de una carpeta `src`, así:

```
src
- edu
  - ltmj
    - prueba
      + MiClase.java
```

Desde la línea de comandos podemos tener lo siguiente:

```
$ cd /ruta/hacia/src
$ javac edu/ltmj/prueba/MiClase.java
$ jar -cvf miLib.jar edu/ltmj/prueba/MiClase.class
```

Esto generará el jar con nombre `miLib.jar` y que contendrá a la clase `MiClase` dentro. Puedes importar este jar en tu proyecto groovy y consumir las clases y componentes que existan en tu jar sin problemas. También puedes generar el jar desde tu IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, NetBeans, etc).

Comment: Muchas garacias muy buena la explicación!